# How to obtain grandchildren from grandparent primary key in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

In Entity Framework, three entities have 1 to many relationships as grandparent, children and grandchildren. How do you obtain an object list of all grandchildren given the grandparent's primary key?

Thank you,

Newby to EF

Comment: When asking a question, you should make sure you give the readers as much information as possible.  For instance, it would very helpful if you provided the class definitions for all of your objects.  It would also be helpful to provide an example of data points, which value you have, and what you expect as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have two one-to-many relationships between those three entities, I guess you could do something like this:

```
int grandparentId=1;
using(var ctx=new YourContext())
{
  var grandparent=ctx.GrandParents.FirstOrDefault(gp=>gp.Id==grandparentId);
  if(grandparent!=null)
  {
    // a list with all the grandchildren
    var grandchildren=grandparent.Children.SelectMany(c=>c.GrandChildren).ToList();
  }
}
```

And, if you are not using lazy loading then you need to use the [`Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.include(v=vs.103).aspx) extension method:

```
int grandparentId=1;
using(var ctx=new YourContext())
{
  var grandparent=ctx.GrandParents.Include(gp=>gp.Children.Select(c=>c.GrandChildren)).FirstOrDefault(gp=>gp.Id==grandparentId);
  if(grandparent!=null)
  {
    // a list with all the grandchildren
    var grandchildren=grandparent.Children.SelectMany(c=>c.GrandChildren).ToList();
  }
}
```

But, as @ErikPhilips said, you need to give more information about your model. Without that information it's difficult to give a concrete answer to your real problem.

Comment: That is a very interesting response. Someday I will learn this ***good*** :)  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, If you think my answer helped you to understand how could you resolve your issue, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi, I now have actually tried your suggestion and found the following issue:  A grandparent may have several children, and FirstOrDefault only gets one child.  I am after all the grandchildren, from all the children of the grandparent.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: In my code with the `FirstOrDefault` call I'm searching an especific grandParent (by its Id), not a child. After obtain the grandParent I return all the grandchildren through all the children. GrandParent have a collection of children (`gp.Children`) and each child have a collection of grand children (`c.GrandChildren`)

Comment: In case you need to know how to create an one-to-many relationship in EF, check this [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know a good explanation of all the query methods available?

Comment: I think a good start could be this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb386964(v=vs.110).aspx). That is going to help you to understand what you could do with Linq to Entities. The trick in my code is the use of the `SelectMany` that flattern several list in a unique list. If you want to see the diferences between the `Select` and the `SelectMany` methods check this other [link](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/linq/N74N160714-Difference-between-Select-and-SelectMany-in-LINQ.html)

Comment: Also, in this [site](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net) you will find all that you need to understand and work with EF.